# Showing the score in a TextView in MainActivity during the game

Tags: java, android

I am trying to show the score in a TextView in the game. Score increases during the game but i can't do it in onCreate() method. Do i need to use an adapter or listener? And how?

Comment: You can create an Interface with one method (e.g. `onScoreChange`). Then in your Activity you implement this interface to update the textView. Then whenever the score changes you simply call the class that is implementing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either your activity implements a custom listener, and registers itself in your game, or use event buses.

I use this one a lot
https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus

Whenever the game catches a new score, it publishes a score event, and all objects registered to it (like your activity) get the event and refresh it's data (the UI in this case).

Answer (score 0):

I did'nt understand well your question but i guess you have your score stored

```
//so you can use an handler and a runnable to update textView each 1000ms
private TextView yourTextView
private mHandler = new Handler();
private Runnable = new Runnable() {
    @override
    public void run() {
            // Check first if the reference to your textView is available
         if(yourTextView !=null) {
            // Get your score some how
           yourTextView.setText(myScore);
          }
        mHandler.postDelayed(this,1000); 
     }
```

};

And in your code when you are ready to display score
do call handler with

```
mHandler.posDelayed(mRunnable,100); // Shorter delay for instant trigger
```

Comment: Actually i dont want update score textview each 1000ms, i want update the score whenever it changes for example when the player makes a move. @thunder413